# Find and conditionally edit text in an XML file

Tags: bash, shell, replace, xml-parsing, find

I have a (XML-)file that has the following content:

```xml
<class>OverAll</class>
        <char>
                <rank> 1</rank>
                <name> yyy</name>
                <level> 9</level>
                <experience>53842</experience>
                <class>xxx</class>
        </char>
        <char>
                <rank> 2</rank>
                <name>aaa</name>
                <level> 9</level>
                <experience>53074</experience>
                <class>zzz</class>
        </char>
```

..and so on. I want to extract the number between the `<experience> </experience>` lines and replace it with a modified version of the number I found between the tag. For example, the file should look like this after the script:

```xml
<class>OverAll</class>
        <char>
                <rank> 1</rank>
                <name> yyy</name>
                <level> 9</level>
                <experience>53.842</experience>
                <class>xxx</class>
        </char>
        <char>
                <rank> 2</rank>
                <name>aaa</name>
                <level> 9</level>
                <experience>53.074</experience>
                <class>zzz</class>
        </char>
```

(I want to add a thousands separator, and values above 1 Million is required. So 2 thousand Separators :)
I am able to find and replace the number, but I dont know how to use the input number and modify it and add it back to the line.

Perhaps someone can help here?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: If you have an XML file, then use an XML tool like [XMLStarlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLStarlet)

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner `sed` can do it, assuming the last three digits are always decimal:

```
sed -zE 's#([[:digit:]]{7,})([[:digit:]]{1})[[:space:]]*(</experience[[:space:]]*>)#\1.\2\3#g;s#([[:digit:]]{3})[[:space:]]*(</experience[[:space:]]*>)#.\1\2#g'
```

`sed` parameters breakdown:

- `-zE`

  - `-z` or `--null-data`:  Separate lines by NULL characters to allow pattern matching across lines, because spaces, tabs and newlines are allowed by the XML syntax before the `>` bracket of a tag.
  - `-E` or `--regexp-extended`: Use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use POSIX `-E`).
- `s#([[:digit:]]{7,})([[:digit:]]{1})[[:space:]]*(</experience[[:space:]]*>)#\1.\2\3#g`:
  Insert a decimal point before the last digit, to experience numbers containing seven plus one (eight) or more digits (Million or more with an extra decimal digit).
- `s#([[:digit:]]{3})[[:space:]]*(</experience[[:space:]]*>)#.\1\2#g`:
  Insert a decimal point before the last three digits, to experience numbers ending with three digits (automatically excludes the Millions experiences already processed by previous `sed` command.

Now keep in mind that it is not parsing the XML either, because it will replace numbers in the `<experience>` tag anywhere in the XML tree.

Regular expressions are not meant to parse markup languages. There are better, more efficient and dedicated tools to manipulate XML with XSLT/XPATH like `saxon`, `xsltproc`, `xmllint`...

Using proper XML processing with `xsltproc`:

`decimal-experience.xsl`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Cosmetic sugar to have the xml declaration header and indent -->
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Cosmetic sugar to remove unneeded spaces in elements -->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Copy all the nodes as-is from the source xml -->
  <xsl:template match="*">

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Process the content of the experience tag within the char tag -->
  <xsl:template match="char/experience/">

    <!-- If the experience is not already in decimal form -->
    <xsl:if test="not(contains(., '.'))">

      <xsl:choose>

        <!-- When the experience is less than a Million -->
        <xsl:when test=". &lt; 9999999">
          <!-- The last three digits are decimals -->
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(. div 1000, '0.000')"/>
        </xsl:when>

        <!-- Otherwise the experience is a Million or more -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <!-- The last digit is decimal -->
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(. div 10, '0.0')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running the XSLT transformation above:

```sh
xsltproc decimal-experience.xsl characters.xml
```

Example output:

I created a valid fictive `characters.xml` with a `span` root tag, because your extract was invalid XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<span>
  <class>OverAll</class>
  <char>
    <rank> 1</rank>
    <name> yyy</name>
    <level> 9</level>
    <experience>53.842</experience>
    <class>xxx</class>
  </char>
  <char>
    <rank> 2</rank>
    <name>aaa</name>
    <level> 9</level>
    <experience>53.074</experience>
    <class>zzz</class>
  </char>
  <char>
    <rank> 3</rank>
    <name>Million</name>
    <level>42</level>
    <experience>5585307.4</experience>
    <class>zzz</class>
  </char>
</span>
```

Comment: Won't that delete the closing tag? Also, extra points for expanding the regex to handle xp > 1M. ;)

Comment: fixed the unwanted deletion of the closing tag

Comment: Question is not specified but if it have to work for values grater than a million. Only last thousand get a dot.

Comment: Thank you. But yes, there can be values above 1 Million. Is there a solution for that? :o)

Comment: Values above 1 Million have only one decimal: `sed -E 's#([[:digit:]]{7,})([[:digit:]]{1})(</experience>)#\1.\2\3#g;s#([[:digit:]]{3})(</experience>)#.\1\2#g'`

Comment: @Gletschernadel you can edit your question to make this Millions experience handling requirement explicit, so readers don't have to scroll down to the comments to find-out.

Comment: I misunderstood the decimal as a thousands marker in the first two, lol

Comment: @Léa Gris: Thank you very much for the response.I tried the xsltproc version but it seems that there is an error: The line with the "lesser than 9999999" has too many 9s. When I reduce the value, the Output is like 129773.8. I tried to change some values but I have no idea how to fix that :)  It schould look like this 1.297.738 (didnt know xsltproc before, but seems like a good choice)

Comment: Try this @Gletschernadel:
`    <!-- If the experience is not already in decimal form -->
    <xsl:if test="not(contains(., '.'))">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(. div 1000, '###,###.000')"/>
    </xsl:if>`

Comment: Thanks. The result looks like this now: <experience>1,097.738</experience> Better, but not ideal :o) Hmm ###,###,### seems not to be possible...